# AVAudioRecorder with mac mini micro

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

I want to use AVAudioRecorder on my mac mini.
But there is no microphone input jack.

I think I should buy earpods to use AVAudioRecorder. Maybe these : http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MD827ZM/A/apple-earpods-with-remote-and-mic

If I plug earpods into mac mini (headphone out), 
will it work inside iPhone & iPad  6.0 Simulator ?

Could I record my voice without debugging into iOS device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I've tested AVAudioRecorder in the Simulator on the mini and it works. But your reluctance to test on a device is a worry. *Always* test on a device, especially where hardware-dependent functionality is concerned (as here).

However, my mini definitely does *not* understand the earpods. You have to use a USB microphone.

Comment: If I understood : I have to buy an USB microphone. Plug it into (jack in) and my headphone into (jack out) to play and record on mac mini. And still buy earpods to be sure it is working very well on my iPad. Thank you matt !

Comment: A USB headset will function both as a microphone in and a headphone out. That's what I use.

Comment: [The audio recording source file here[(https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2857188/AudioDemo.zip) is not working for me on the iPhone simulator my Mac mini with a usb headset. I have altered System Preferences to recognize the headset and have tested the headset with other commercial apps. Is there a preference that must be set inside Xcode for this project to work on the Mac Mini?